# SQL query to add column datediff calculated in months

Tags: sql, ms-access

in the ms access database

columnA has date entries

```
collumnA
01/15/08
02/11/08
12/23/08
```

how do i write a query to add new column called months.

where months are calculated as

months = no. of months between  original date to 01 dec 2009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT datediff("m",[collumnA],#2009/12/01#) As NoMonth FROM SomeTable
```

More here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP011407141033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT  DateDiff("m",[collumnA],#01/Dec/2009#) FROM YourTable
```